# What are the different meanings of "hey yourself"?

Tags: idioms

while I'm doing some research about the meaning of "hey yourself" I found that it means just "greet back", but does it mean something else like "don't speak this way"?

Comment: Related : http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73608/is-it-appropriate-to-use-hey-yourself

Comment: As Josh has pointed out, this is already covered by another question. However I think there is another point to make. This is not restricted to 'hey'.  The general form is that one person says, "XXXXX" and the other person replies "XXXXX yourself".  It is another way of saying, "The same to you!" or "You too!".